# Refresh HTML Data Table from csv file

Tags: java

I need help pls...

I have build a webpage with navbar menus. Well all menus are linked with different pages.
Question - have a data csv file and I need to update the data in html table using javascript. It works on local server ; however, once I do edit the csv file and refresh the web-page the table contents won't update automatically.

Pls help.

```
<head>
<!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />

<title>RTA | WFM </title>

<link href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="nav-md">
<div class="container body">
<div class="main_container">
<div class="col-md-3 left_col">
<div class="left_col scroll-view">
<div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
<a href="index.html" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> <span>WFM | RTA</span></a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<br />
<!-- sidebar menu -->
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
<div class="menu_section">
<h3>General</h3>
<ul class="nav side-menu">
<li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="nav child_menu">
<li><a href="Non-Adherence.html">Non-Adherence</a></li>
<li><a href="Planned Vs Actual.html">Planned Vs Actual Count</a></li>
<li><a href="Zone Summary.html">Zone Summary</a></li>
<li><a href="Shift Wise Absenteeism.html">Shift Wise Absenteeism</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Roster <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="nav child_menu"> 
<li><a href="Current Roster.html">Current Roster</a></li>
<li><a href="Next Roster.html">Next Adherence</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="nav child_menu">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> LE Disconnection <span class="label label-success pull-right">Coming Soon</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> Body Swap <span class="label label-success pull-right">Coming Soon</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Data Presentation <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="nav child_menu">
<li><a href="chartjs.html">Chart JS</a></li>
<li><a href="chartjs2.html">Chart JS2</a></li>
<li><a href="morisjs.html">Moris JS</a></li>
<li><a href="echarts.html">ECharts</a></li>
<li><a href="other_charts.html">Other Charts</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /sidebar menu -->
<!-- /menu footer buttons -->
<div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small">
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Settings">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="FullScreen">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lock">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Logout" href="login.html">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
</div>
<!-- /menu footer buttons -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
<!-- top tiles -->
<div class="row tile_count">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
<span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Pay Monthly</span>
<div class="count">2500</div>
<span class="count_bottom"><i class="green">4% </i> From last Week</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
<span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Home Broadband</span>
<div class="count">123.50</div>
<span class="count_bottom"><i class="green">4% </i> From last Week</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
<span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Upgrades</span>
<div class="count">2,500</div>
<span class="count_bottom"><i class="green">4% </i> From last Week</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
<span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Pay & Go</span>
<div class="count">4,567</div>
<span class="count_bottom"><i class="green">4% </i> From last Week</span>
</div>
<!-- /top tiles -->
<!--table data -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="x_panel">
<div class="x_title">
<h2>Planned Vs Actual <small>Summary</small></h2>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="x_content">
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Skill</th>
<th>Lock Hours</th>
<th>Actual Count</th>
<th>Away%</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<div id="container"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /page content -->
<!-- footer content -->
<footer>
<div class="pull-right">WFM Admin Template by Ankur Khera</a></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</footer>
<!-- /footer content -->
</div>
</div>
<script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/skycons/skycons.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/flot.orderbars/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/flot-spline/js/jquery.flot.spline.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/flot.curvedlines/curvedLines.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/DateJS/build/date.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/weather/weather.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/csv_to_html_table.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/custom.min.js"></script>
</body> 
<script>
$.get('employee1.csv', function(data) {
// start the table  
var html = '<table class="table table-hover">';
// split into lines
var rows = data.split("\n");
// parse lines
rows.forEach( function getvalues(ourrow) {
// start a table row
html += "<tr>";
// split line into columns
var columns = ourrow.split(",");

html += "<td>" + columns[0] + "</td>";
html += "<td>" + columns[1] + "</td>";
html += "<td>" + columns[2] + "</td>";
html += "<td>" + columns[3] + "</td>";

// close row
html += "</tr>";    
})
// close table
html += "</table>";

// insert into div
$('#container').append(html);
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your JS code that listens for the updated file and refreshes the DOM?

Comment: @ Rick. If you see my above code, I have created a function which will look for csv file and update it to html table.
$.get('employee1.csv', function(data) {......................

Comment: i don't know if there would be another js file. I do update the csv database from excel macro but refreshing won't refresh table data. I need to ctrl+refresh